# TypeError: json.find is not a function (discord.js)

Tags: arrays, json, find, discord.js

i tried find solve the problems "json.find" to display item and price
****for example****
type`.shop basic kibble`

**bot** reply `Name: Basic Kibble cost: k50`

or type `.shop food`
**bot** reply `Name:Food cost k10`

in bot.js

```js
bot.on("message", ({ author, channel, content }) => {
  if (author.bot || !content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  const args = content.slice(prefix.length).split(" ");
  const command = args.shift();

  if (command === "shop") {
    if (!args.length) return message.channel.send("You must specify an item!");

    const input = args.join(" ");
    const items = json.find((object) => object.name === `item`);
    if (!items) return channel.send(`${input} isn't a valid item!`);

    channel.send(`Name: ${items.name} Cost: k${items.cost}`);
  }
});
```

Comment: in shop.json file

```
{"item": [
    {
    "name": "Basic Kibble",
    "cost": 50
    },
    {
        "name": "food",
        "cost": 10
    }
]
}```

Comment: Do you ever require or import the json file?

Comment: Where do you define "json"

Comment: const json = require("./data/shop.json"); at the top of bot.js

Comment: try `json.JSON().find()`

Comment: is not a function.

Comment: What does your json file look like? Is it one big array, or an array within some json?

Comment: {
    "item": {
        "name": "Basic Kibble",
        "cost": 50
    
    },
    "item2": {
        "name": "Jerky Meat",
        "cost": 10
    }
}

Comment: im not sure if i doing json file in right order way. and if i successful tested and json will be big array cos there will be more 100+ items

Answer (score 0):

You said the following in your comment:
"in shop.json file  `{"item": [ { "name": "Basic Kibble", "cost": 50 }, { "name": "food", "cost": 10 } ] }`"

If json is this, it means that it's an object. You would need to use:

```js
const items = json.item.find(object => object.name === `item`)
```